# Is there any way to identify (part/serial number, etc.) whether a given keyboard is mechanical or membrane type?

Tags: keyboard

Is there any special kind of designation for a keyboard type?

I would like to know whether some keyboard is mechanical or membrane style.

Can I identify this just by reading some information on keyboard sticker (*`serial id or part number, etc`*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, most probably not.

Some manufacturers might include information about the switch type on the keyboard itself, but the best way to find out is to visit the manufacturers web page and look at the technical details of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You would be best to reference deskthority wiki, just type in the serial number and then 'deskthority wiki' and you should have some info on it